# Notifications app android from email address

Tags: java, android, email, push-notification, notifications

In an android business app I have to receive communications from the management of the staff.

Personnel management uses a mail client (Outlook) to send communications.

These communications can be for all employees or just for some.

I thought I would create a specific mailbox for the app and make sure it is included in classical communications.

With the app, I track this specific mailbox and when I receive a message, I make a notification.

Because when sending business communications, however, the BCC field is used, I can not recover email addresses from email message for verify if the comunication is for a specific employe.

Do you know some other way or method for notifying everyone or selectively from a communication sent by email?

Comment: Isn't the mail server responsible for this stuff? Every person in the business already has a mail box. The server deals with email-lists, forwards, replies, CCs and BCCs. A mail for a certain person is in his or her mailbox, when it was directed to that person. From your app you check the mailbox for new mail and show the notifications. Why would you want an extra mailbox?

Comment: Unfortunately several employees do not directly use corporate email and redirect emails to other mailboxes without retaining a copy of the email